# How to auto adjust left/right div tags width to fit the screen whilst keeping the middle div width static

Tags: html, css

Hi how do I get div 'one' and div 'three' auto adjusted to screen side whilst keeping div 'two' width static in css? all three divs should be in the same row

my HTML goes as this;

```
<html>
<header<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="x">
  <div id="one"></div>
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div id="three"></div>
</div><!-- close div 'x' -->
</body>
</html>
```

and the CSS done so far is as follows;

```
    #x {height:34px; border:1px solid gray;}
#one {height:30px; border:1px solid red;; width:auto; float:left;}
#two {height:30px; border:1px solid green; width:660px; float:left;}
#thr {height:30px; border:1px solid blue; width:auto; float:left;}
```

any suggestions greatly appreciated. Thanks for looking

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DejUn/)

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="static"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-align:stretch; 
     display:-moz-box;      
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    -moz-box-align:stretch;
    display:box;
    box-orient:horizontal;
    box-align:stretch;   
    color: #ffffff;    
}    

div {
    height: auto;
}

.first {
    background-color: #546547;   
}

.static {
    background-color: #154d67;
    width: 660px;  
}

.third {
    background-color: #c00000;   
}

.first, .third {
    -webkit-box-flex:1.0;
    -moz-box-flex:1.0;
    box-flex:1.0;
}
​
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure you match the ids.
`thr` is not the same as `three`.

The changes I've done to the css:

1. Indent it. It's good practice.
2. Declare widths of the divs in percentage of the parent div's size. You hadn't declared the widths at all.
3. Added a little `padding`, so that the 3 inner divs stay at the center of the outer div

Here's the CSS:

```
#x 
 {
  position:relative;
  padding:1.5px;
  height:34px;
  border:1px solid gray;
 }
#one 
 { 
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid red;
  width:33%;
  float:left; 
 }
#two 
 {
  height:30px; 
  border:1px solid green; 
  width:33%;
  float:left;
 }
#three 
 {
  height:30px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  width:33%;
  float:left;
 }
```

Comment: He needs div 2 to be static... :)