# I have 3 divs in one row, how do I get the middle div to stay an exact width while the left and right div shrink in as the screen resizes smaller?

Tags: css, html

I have 3 divs in one row

`<div id="left"></div>`
`<div id="middle"></div>`
`<div id="right"></div>`

here's how its layed out

I need the middle div to stay a fix width, but the left and right divs to shrink in as the screen gets smaller, heres an example

how would I write out the css?

this is how I have it so far, and by the way the 3 divs are wrapped in another div#mid

`#mid {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 395px;
    max-height: 395px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F00; 
    display: block;
}`

`#left {
    min-width:35%;
    min-height: 395px;
    max-height: 395px;
    background-color: #00F;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}`

`#middle {
    min-width:30%;
    min-height: 395px;
    max-height: 395px;
    background-color: #3F0;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}`

`#right {
    min-width:35%;
    min-height: 395px;
    max-height: 395px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: #0FF;
    position:relative;
    float: left;
}`
if anyone can help me out id really appreciate it, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12766567/how-to-auto-adjust-left-right-div-tags-width-to-fit-the-screen-whilst-keeping-th/12766766#12766766) I've answered this question, you can do it like this : [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DejUn/1/)

```
<div class="container">
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="static"></div>
<div class="third"></div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
    -webkit-box-align:stretch; 
     display:-moz-box;      
    -moz-box-orient:horizontal;
    -moz-box-align:stretch;
    display:box;
    box-orient:horizontal;
    box-align:stretch;   
    color: #ffffff;    
}    

div {
    height: auto;
}

.first {
    background-color: #546547;   
}

.static {
    background-color: #154d67;
    width: 300px;  
}

.third {
    background-color: #c00000;   
}

.first, .third {
    -webkit-box-flex:1.0;
    -moz-box-flex:1.0;
    box-flex:1.0;
}
​
```

Comment: this worked great, I am having a problem on having a fixed height of all 3 divs. How would I have all 3 div's stay at a height of 390px?

Comment: @user1740297 here you go, and if you think this helped you should mark this answer as correct http://jsfiddle.net/DejUn/2/

Comment: I updated the link http://jsfiddle.net/DejUn/5/ and added more demo text to the first div, when i shrink the screen size it pushes the height to be bigger. I need the height to stay fixed

Comment: @user1740297 look closely, height stays fixed :)

Comment: just the content inside gets wrapped

Comment: in the left div, I have a list of text. As I re-size the screen smaller, the text pushes down. How can I get the text to not push down as the screen get smaller?

Comment: Use `min-width` http://jsfiddle.net/DejUn/9/ and btw if this answer has helped you than select it as a correct answer so that others can refer :)

Comment: just click on the tick below up and down arrows.. :)

Comment: @MrAlien Does the css for the box stretch and box orient work on internet explorer? I am having major issues showing on internet explorer. Is there a css I can use for internet explorer to show correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple give fixed width to the middle div like `width:300px`...Hope this will be useful...

Comment: ya i have checked after resizing the window but after certain limit the last div comes down....http://jsfiddle.net/gxa4j/2/

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple.

1. Float the three divs.
2. Set the display property to 'inline-block'.
3. Set the width attribute of middle div.
4. Set max width attribute of the left & right div.

Here is the HTML markup I have tested with:

```
<body>
    <div id="left">LEFT CONTENT ... LEFT CONTENT ... LEFT CONTENT ... LEFT CONTENT</div>
    <div id="middle"></div>
    <div id="right">
        RIGHT CONTENT ... RIGHT CONTENT ... RIGHT CONTENT ... RIGHT CONTENT
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is a sample CSS:

```
#right,
#left {
 background-color:green;
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 max-width:20%;
 min-height:20px;
}
​#middle {
 width: 60%;
 float:left;
 display:inline-block;
 background-color:blue;
 min-height:20px;
}​
```

And here is the implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/3yEv3/

Comment: OP asks for a fixed width. this is fluid.

Comment: Feel Free to change width:60% to width:200px or 300px :)
My Bad! Updated the jsFiddle Link.